# SQL count entries over multiple thresholds

Tags: sql

I am using SQL and I have a table that looks like this

| ID | Score | Check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 500 | 1 |
| 3 | 600 | 1 |
| 4 | 900 | 0 |
| 5 | 400 | 1 |
| 6 | 100 | 0 |
| 7 | 200 | 1 |
| 8 | 500 | 0 |
| 9 | 500 | 0 |

I want to return a table like this that counts the number of rows where score is greater than the values in the first column and also the number of 1s left in those rows:

| Greater Than | Count Rows | Count Checks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 9 | 5 |
| 200 | 6 | 3 |
| 400 | 5 | 2 |
| 600 | 1 | 0 |
| 800 | 1 | 0 |
| 1000 | 0 | 0 |

I don't know how to do this in SQL for multiple thresholds.

I know that to do this for one threshold it would look like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(Check) 
FROM table_name
WHERE Score>200
```

I thought something like this might work

```
SELECT count(*), SUM(Check) 
FROM sql_test_a 
WHERE Score>(SELECT threshold FROM sql_test_b)
```

But I am new to SQL and can't work it out

Comment: Would you mind sharing the database you're using? (MySQL/OracleDB/PostgreSQL/...?) SQL queries often differ (slightly) based on the SQL dialect of the database you chose.

Comment: You have column name inconsistency here, your table's column names don't match the queries.

Comment: Sorry, fixed naming inconsistency! I'm using OracleDB I think? It's on Bigquery in GCP

Comment: The desired result is incorrect, the count rows should be 1 for values 600 and 800 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a predefined table containing the necessary values for the final select and then merge it with your table using the condition `Score > val`

```
select r.val as "Greater Than", count(t.Score) as "Count Rows", sum(coalesce(Chck,0)) as "Count Checks"
from (
  select 0 AS val union all
  select 200 union all
  select 400 union all
  select 600 union all
  select 800 union all
  select 1000
) as r
left join mytable t on t.Score > r.val
group by r.val
order by r.val
```

Results :

```
Greater Than    Count Rows  Count Checks
0               9           5
200             6           3
400             5           2
600             1           0
800             1           0
1000            0           0
```

[Demo on mysql](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q7Rb3lV_)

Comment: `sum(coalesce(Chck,0))` what's the point of the `coalesce` and if you really need it then why not `isnull` which is generally more performant? Good answer anyway.

Comment: Note that the ISO/ANSI SQL uses double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"Greater Than"`. (No dbms tagged.)

Comment: Good remarks, although `COALESCE` is widely supported by the majority of RDBMS, unlike `ISNULL.`

Comment: This worked thanks every much!

Answer (score -1):

You can have this simple union query,

```
select greater_than as "Greater Than", count_rows as "Count Rows", count_checks as "Count Checks"
from
(select score as greater_than, count(1) as count_rows, sum(check) as count_checks 
from table where score > 0
union all
select score as greater_than, count(1) as count_rows, sum(check) as count_checks 
from table where score > 200
union all
select score as greater_than, count(1) as count_rows, sum(check) as count_checks 
from table where score > 400
union all
select score as greater_than, count(1) as count_rows, sum(check) as count_checks 
from table where score > 600
union all
select score as greater_than, count(1) as count_rows, sum(check) as count_checks 
from table where score > 800
union all
select score as greater_than, count(1) as count_rows, sum(check) as count_checks 
from table where score > 1000) T1 order by greater_than;
```

Comment: Not sure why this is any different to the other answer below, which is also dog slow. The other left-join answer is much better